# Selenium, InternetExplorerDriver, ForceCreateProcessApi, timeout or no browser launch?

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

We've been using Selenium to automate some browser testing in Internet Explorer.  On Windows 7 32-bit it works fine.  However we're testing it on Windows 10 64-bit and it fails miserably.

- Sometimes the browser doesn't even launch
- If i change the driver versions, i can get the browser to launch but it hangs on the first page
- The issue is only present when I use ForceCreateProcessApi.  However I need to use ForceCreateProcessApi in order to use BrowserCommandLineArguments!
- The exception is:  The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:16639/session timed out after 60 seconds.

Here is the PowerShell code i use:

```
$seleniumOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerOptions
$seleniumOptions.InitialBrowserUrl = $SiteUrl
$seleniumOptions.ForceCreateProcessApi = $true
$seleniumOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-k"
$seleniumOptions.IgnoreZoomLevel = $true

New-Variable -Name IEDS -Value ([OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriverService]) -Force
$defaultservice = $IEDS::CreateDefaultService()
        
$seleniumDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver -ArgumentList @($defaultservice, $seleniumOptions)
```

I've tried the following versions (x86 and x64 versions), and none of them work:

```
2.25.3
3.141
3.9.0
```

Can anybody advise on how to make this work?  I've made sure that TabProcGrowth etc is set according to the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a 3.150.1 32-bit driver.

I'm not sure how it looks on PS - but I'm able to run IE with this driver config.

```json
ie: { version: "3.150.1", arch: "ia32" }
```

Also I have a key for iexplore.exe here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`

from this [config link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've tried all this - I've placed the x64 driver exe in the system32 folder, the x86 driver exe in the SysWOW64 folder, I've used the 3.141.0 WebDriver and WebSupport DLLs, I've ensured FEATURE_FCACHE is in HKLM and HKLM\Wow6432Node locations, and HKCU too, I've ensured Enhanced Protection Mode is off, I've ensure zoom is set to 100% too.  What a pain....

Comment: But I wrote about FEATURE_BFCACHE and 3.150.1. And you don't need to put anything to system32 and SysWOW64. And yes, PS with selenium is a pain. Why don't you switch to C#?

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the typos above. In the end I've refactored the solution to use the Chrome driver. Less buggy and works faster! I did set the registry value above, and tried the version you mentioned too.